# Copy/paste not working in VirtualBox with XP as guest OS on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, virtualization, windows-xp

I'm unable to copy/paste or drag/drop in Sun VirtualBox with Windows XP as Guest OS on Ubuntu 13.04.

I've already checked the settings to **Bidirectional**. Still am unable to execute these operations.

Comment: Did you install the Guest additions (in Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

Same bug here, on Ubuntu 13.04 and XP.

What worked for me was the following:

- Install Guest additions
- Create a folder in your Ubuntu Home directory.
- In VB main menu on the upper side go to "advices" (third item) and then click on **Shared folders**. Click on **Add folder**. Select path - other, select your created folder or any other you are working in. Mark automount and make permanent. Ok. Restart VB.

Now in the MS explorer you can access your folder easily and use it to pass information from one OS to the other.